# sudo/apt-get command not found in git bash

Tags: linux, git-bash

I am using Windows 10 in my machine, and currently installed git bash on it.

I wanted to install node and npm for my application.

when i tried :

apt-get install nodejs

"apt-get" command not found,

I tried google and got

sudo install nodejs

"sudo" command not found.

How to use sudo and apt-get command on my git bash.

Comment: git-bash != ubuntu; you might want to install/setup the Windows Ubuntu bash support instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) comes with a Windows port of [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and a collection of few more common *nix command-line tools that have been *compiled for Windows*, it does not provide a complete *nix environment. Hence you cannot use tools like `sudo` and `apt-get` which modify the *nix operating system.

However, there are other tools, programs if you like, available.

Try to install node " [the windows way](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) ".

Answer (score 2):

[win-sudo](https://github.com/imachug/win-sudo) package adds `sudo` to windows.

kafaior at Super User [suggests](https://superuser.com/a/845220/659759):

> A working sudo replacement for Cygwin's mintty terminal would be to place the following script in user's PATH:

```
$!/bin/bash
cygstart --action=runas mintty -e `which bash` -lc \"$@\"
```

[Maximus](https://superuser.com/a/493133/659759) mentions how to add `sudo` (well, csudo) via cmder.

Super User has a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows).
It looks like there is a command `runas` or `elevate` commands.  These might be for PowerShell, rather than git bash. I'm not sure.

I found your this while looking for a way to add `rsync` to Git Bash.  So below I included info that may or may not work for `sudo` or `apt-get`.  If they do not work directly for specific commands the OP is asking about, they may inspire a solution that does work.  Also this could help others who arrived here as I did.

`rsync` is another unix command not available in the standard installation of git bash.
However, you can download and install the [Git for Windows SDK](https://gitforwindows.org/) (scroll to the bottom of the page for the link).  This will allow you to create a version of the Git for Windows installer that *does* include additional *nx commands.

Install the Git for Windows SDK according to the instructions.  Part 2 is where you add the packages you want, that aren't included in the standard git bash installation. Part 3 is where you create a Git installer, which will include the additional packages.  If you skipped step 2, this should produce an installer similar to the standard installer..  There is a good discussion as to why they cannot include these commands in the general distribution.

It is also possible to just grab `rsync` file[here](https://gist.github.com/hisplan/ee54e48f17b92c6609ac16f83073dde6) or [here](http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/) and unpack it directly within your Git installation, and it works.  I dunno if it is also possible to do something similar for `sudo` or `apt-get`.

Finally, it looks like there is a way to get *nix commands available within the Git Bash shell via [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/master/README.md).  Here are the [instructions](https://www.awmoore.com/2015/01/14/setting-up-git-and-cmder/).

Answer (score 1):

Installing applications in git bash does not sound right to me. I would suggest you either use the native Windows installer (https://nodejs.org/) or, if you prefer a package manager, use Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/) to install nodejs with:

```
choco install nodejs
```