# Git Bash | bash: sudo: command not found (and others)

Tags: bash, git-bash, sudo, apt, su

Goal: get **Poetry** working.

Using **Git Bash** on **Windows 10** with **WSL 2**.

I have Anaconda3 and Git working.

`pip install bash` worked but did not help.

---

Git Bash:

```
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ sudo -s
bash: sudo: command not found
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ su -
bash: su: command not found
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ apt update
bash: apt: command not found
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ apt install sudo -y
bash: apt: command not found
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
$ cat ~/.bashrc
. /c/Users/dabell/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
(base)
```

These commands work in WSL 2.

Comment: Git bash ships with a few linux utility programs, neither apt nor sudo are in the package. If you want a linux environment you should try WSL.

Comment: Ah ok, so is this normal behaviour then? Yes, WSL 2 works re those commands

Comment: It is not necessary to have `sudo` command in **Git Bash**. If you need sudo then you can just run **Git Bash** as Administrator. I needed it for `dd` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @tkausl, **Git Bash does not come with such commands**.

I've also found a similar post on Stack Overflow, the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285903/16852041) stating the same.